# Durandal router - how to define view as modal in routes definition

Tags: durandal, single-page-application, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

How can I declare view to be opened as modal directly on click?

My route's definition is:

```
var routes = [
    { route: '', moduleId: 'home', title: 'My Apps', nav: true },
    { route: 'aboutus', moduleId: 'aboutus', title: 'About Us', nav: true },
    { route: 'help', moduleId: 'help', title: 'Help', nav: true },
    { route: 'faq', moduleId: 'faq', title: 'FAQ', nav: true },
    { route: 'contactus', moduleId: 'contactus', title: 'Contact', nav: true }
];
```

I want to open 'contactus' module as modal dialog on a current screen - don't want to navigate to another view.

Have no idea how to acomplish that.
Many thanks for suggestions.

Comment: You don't do this from your router.  In your shell view model you can show a modal that is shared around the application.  Follow these instructions - http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create Custom modal
2. Use Compose binding
3. Modifed router on shell view and model

create custom modal

**CustomModal.html**

```
<div class="modal-content messageBox">
    <div class="modal-header">
        Custom modal example
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div data-bind="compose: $root.moduleId"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: ok">Ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CustomModal.js**

```
define(['plugins/dialog', 'knockout'], function (dialog, ko) {

    var customModal = function(moduleId)
    {
       this.moduleId = moduleId;
    };

    customModal.prototype.ok = function()
    {
       dialog.close(this);
    };

    customModal.show = function(moduleId)
    {
       return dialog.show(new customModal(moduleId));
    };

    return customModal;
});
```

and then, modified shell.js and shell.html

**shell.js**

```
define(['plugins/router', '../customModal'], function(router, customModal)
{ 
   var modified_routes = [
     // Normal route configuration
     { route: '', moduleId: 'home', title: 'My Apps', nav: true },
     { route: 'aboutus', moduleId: 'aboutus', title: 'About Us', nav: true },

     // Modified route configuration, included add-on property
     { 
       route: 'contactus', 
       moduleId: 'contactus', 
       title: 'Contact', 
       nav: true, 
       showOnModal: true // add-on property
     }
   ];

   return {
      showModal: function(data)
      {
         customModal.show(data.moduleId);
      },
      activate: function()
      {
         router.map(modified_routes).buildNavigationModel().activate();
      }
   }  
});
```

**shell.html**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
    <li>
         <!-- ko if: ! showOnModal -->
         <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }"><span data-bind="text: title"></span></a>
         <!-- /ko -->

         <!-- ko if: showOnModal -->
         <a data-bind="click: $root.showModal"><span data-bind="text: title"></span></a>
         <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this solution but received exception: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return shell.router.navigationModel }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return !showOnModal }"
Message: showOnModal is not defined;

Comment: I added showOnModal: false to the other routes - now it's working! thanks!

Comment: Hi @ej_ja, maybe you should try <!-- ko if: typeof showOnModal !== 'undefined' && showOnModal --> so you don't need to added showOnModal property on the other routes. *I'm not sure this would work

Comment: @ej_ja You won't get that error (and won't need to put `showOnModal: false` everywhere) if you just check for `showOnModal` as a property of `$data`: `<!-- ko if: ! $data.showOnModal -->`.